# shape back color

Tags: c#, forms, graphics

I have created a User Control using graphic's fill property. It's a circle. It's like a speedometer hence it has many colors and filled using different shapes. I need to have it's empty space to have back color to some thing other than the default color. How to change the back color of the graphic's shape???

Comment: Did my last post answer this question? or do you still need more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Pens, Brushes and Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983677(VS.71).aspx)

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
g.FillEllipse(myBrush, ClientRectangle);
```

A more complete example.  This will fill the background of the UserControl (based on the size of the user control) to Pink, and create a small circle that is filled with an orange backgroung color.

```
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
     Graphics g = e.Graphics;

     SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Pink);
     g.FillRectangle(sb, e.ClipRectangle);
     sb.Dispose();

     sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
     g.FillEllipse(sb, 20, 20, 20, 20);
     sb.Dispose();
  }
```

Is this more what you are looking for?

If you want the background color to be the same as the user control, change this:

```
SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor); //Color.Pink);
```

Comment: If i'm not wrong that will draw the shape in RED color. I have drawn the shape in circle it's like a speedometer but I want to set that empty space that is having form color to another color.
For example.
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
g.FillEllipse(myBrush, ClientRectangle);
it creates a rectangle in red shape but inside that rectangle I want some other color. Hope it's clear...

Comment: Ok, I updated my example, let me know if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey that's great I'll try with my code and let you know thanks.